# How to permit secondary profile to create/manage hotspot

Tags: root-access, permissions, wifi-hotspot, profiles

How can I modify the permissions of my Android's secondary profile/user to be able to create & manage a WiFi hotspot on the device?

I'm running Android 11 (LineageOS). I have a secondary user that I would like to be able to manage the hotspot. However, when I navigate to Settings -> Network & Internet -> Hotspot & tethering, I see the following error message:

> Tethering settings are not available for this user.

I also have the credentials for the primary user profile.

I also have root on this device.

How can I modify the permissions of this secondary user profile such that they can create and manage the hotspot settings on the handset?

Comment: For context: I'm trying to share a large file between my Android phone and my laptop. My current WiFi won't allow clients to connect to each other, so I want to use a hotspot. The primary user can't see the file as it's owned by the secondary user. The secondary user can't share the file because they can't manage the hotspot on my phone to bypass the LAN's firewall fuckery. The file is too large to copy around. My laptop can't take the file over USB because it's running QubesOS. There's other solutions, but the easiest would be to just let the secondary user manage the hotspot.

Comment: See also https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246200/hotspot-dhcp-issues-without-mobile-data-dhcp4-request-timed-out

Comment: Please just integrate your comments into your question and delete them.

Comment: See also https://github.com/onionshare/onionshare/issues/567#issuecomment-1091963143

Comment: @Robert the comment is not necessarily relevant to the question as the question is intentionally more broad than my specific use-case.

Answer (score -1):

Hotspot from the admin account then switch to the user account. Otherwise it is not possible to hotspot from the user account. Set up all your hot spot from the admin account before switching to the user account.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Perhaps it's possible with root and XPosed framework.