# Hotspot DHCP issues without mobile data (dhcp4 request timed out)

Tags: linux, networking, wifi-hotspot, dhcp

By default, does the Android "hotspot" functionality provide a DHCP server to its clients? Or does it just pass DHCP info on from the network that it's connected to?

I'm trying to create a hotspot for LAN-only communication between my laptop and my phone. I do not have a SIM card, so **"Mobile Data" is disabled**." I also don't have access to another WiFI network, so **"WiFi" is disabled**.

I created a hotspot and try to connect to it from my laptop, but I get this error from NetworkManager's logs (I'm using GNU/Debian 11 Linux):

```
[user@sys-net ~]$ sudo journalctl -u NetworkManager -f
...
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.7570] device (wls6): Activation: starting connection '<SSID_REDACTED>' (501ce9ff-854f-472a-81cd-5eb447c47379)
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.7585] device (wls6): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> interface_disabled
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.7585] device (p2p-dev-wls6): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> interface_disabled
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.7654] device (wls6): supplicant interface state: interface_disabled -> disconnected
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.7655] device (p2p-dev-wls6): supplicant management interface state: interface_disabled -> disconnected
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.7667] device (wls6): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.7675] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.7840] device (wls6): set-hw-addr: set-cloned MAC address to <MAC_ADDRESS_REDACTED> (stable)
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.8065] device (wls6): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.8087] device (wls6): Activation: (wifi) access point '<SSID_REDACTED>' has security, but secrets are required.
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.8087] device (wls6): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.8248] device (wls6): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> interface_disabled
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.8248] device (p2p-dev-wls6): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> interface_disabled
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.8250] device (wls6): supplicant interface state: interface_disabled -> disconnected
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.8250] device (p2p-dev-wls6): supplicant management interface state: interface_disabled -> disconnected
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.8405] device (wls6): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.8412] device (wls6): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.8461] device (wls6): Activation: (wifi) connection '<SSID_REDACTED>' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.8473] Config: added 'ssid' value '<SSID_REDACTED>'
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.8474] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.8474] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.8474] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.8474] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.8475] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.9055] device (wls6): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.9059] device (p2p-dev-wls6): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.9109] device (wls6): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.9110] device (p2p-dev-wls6): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.9365] device (wls6): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4way_handshake
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.9365] device (p2p-dev-wls6): supplicant management interface state: associating -> 4way_handshake
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.9611] device (wls6): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.9611] device (wls6): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "<SSID_REDACTED>"
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.9611] device (p2p-dev-wls6): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.9616] device (wls6): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 07 16:15:24 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340924.9621] dhcp4 (wls6): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
...
... <here it got stuck waiting for an IP address before timing out>
...
Apr 07 16:16:10 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <warn>  [1649340970.5783] dhcp4 (wls6): request timed out
Apr 07 16:16:10 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340970.5783] dhcp4 (wls6): state changed unknown -> timeout
Apr 07 16:16:10 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340970.5784] device (wls6): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 07 16:16:10 sys-net NetworkManager[1446]: <info>  [1649340970.5799] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
```

Why is my android device failing to provide my laptop with an IP Address? Is it because my android isn't already connected to another network running a DHCP server? How can I make my android hotpsot provide a DHCP IP address to my laptop when I connect to my android's hotspot?

Comment: See also [How to permit secondary profile to create/manage hotspot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246199/how-to-permit-secondary-profile-to-create-manage-hotspot)

Comment: See also [Stack Overflow - Android Wi-fi AP hotspot - without internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686992/android-wi-fi-ap-hotspot-without-internet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was caused by my firewall and due to complexity between multiple user profiles.

I was able to fix all issues by entirely disabling the firewall setup by the `afwall` app.

However, as a slightly better option, I was able to fix this issue as follows:

1. As the 'Owner' profile, **enable** `Airplane mode`. Make sure `WiFi` **and** `Mobile Data` **are off** if you want to use the phone's own internal DHCP server. Then **enable** `Hotspot`
2. In the user's account where `afwall` is configured, check the box to give "wifi" access to the row named `(any app) - Same as selecting all apps - !! WARNING !!`

> Note: I did try to isolate the wifi permissions to a single app, but I found that if every app's "wifi" setting was enabled (except the entry for `(any app)` of course), then it wouldn't work. But if the "wifi" setting was enabled for the `(any app)` row, then it worked.
>
> So it appears that there is, in fact, a distinction between selecting all apps or selecting the `(any app)` entry. My guess is this distinction is most relevant when using multiple user profiles.

On another handset, I was able to resolve this issue and get an IP address when only enabling the "wifi" permission for the `(root) - Apps running as root` entry (as opposed to the `(any app)` entry). YMMV device-to-device, version-to-version, ROM-to-ROM.

Answer (score 0):

This question is linked in comments in [other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686992/android-wi-fi-ap-hotspot-without-internet) with ***Highly active question*** rank but excessive reputation points are needed to answer it. So I answer here because those two questions are linked, and answer explains mentioned there problem.

On Samsung phones it is not possible to turn on hotspot without inserted SIM card.
But there are tools to create in newer Android versions *offline hotspot* - [more info here](https://code.briarproject.org/briar/briar/-/issues/1646)

Comment: Except the Op has it working.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/257312)